# android - where to save history and autocomplete values

Tags: android, storage, sharedpreferences

my history objects only have 2 fields (id + name). i have to save them. i used sharedpreferences because this is just perfect to save key-value pairs. problem is..there is no possibilty to change to location where the files are saved. i dont want to save them into the sharedpref folder because i want to give the user of the app the possibility to delete all history entries. i have to check which files are history files and which files are preferences files used by the app. this is no proble..but dirty imo. on the other hand..my history files shouldnt be in sharedpref folder..they have nothing to do in that folder..

the other possibility is to store the data in internal storage as xml for example. i would have to write a serializer and parser.

the third possibility (i just remembered writing this question)is to save it via Java Properties. this is probably the easiest solution. its like sharedpref

the last possibility is to store it in sqlite. i dont know..my data is so tiny..and i use a databae to store it?

my question is simply..what do u recommend to use and why. what do you use? same question belongs to the autocomplete values. id like to save the values the user once entered in a textfield. where to save them? where do you save such data?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate sharedpreferences file for your history using (say) `Context.getSharedPreferences("history")` which will create a sharedpreferences file as follows.

```
/data/data/com.your.package.name/shared_prefs/history.xml
```

But I'm pretty sure that all sharedpreferences files will be created in `/data/data/com.your.package.name/shared_prefs/`. I don't think you can change the location.

Comment: but i have not just one history file. i have several. maybe 1..maybe 20..depends on the user. everytime the user has a look at a certain product..a history file entry should be added. and yes..the sharedpref location cant be changed!

Comment: So just create a series of history files with a suitable name for each as the user looks at the related product.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mis-interpreting your objective but for something like this I would just straight-up use a BufferedWriter from `java.io.BufferedWriter` to write a new file for each object. Likewise you can read the data with a BufferedReader. The code would look something like this:

```
 public static void save(FileIO files){
            BufferedWriter out = null;
            try{
                //use a writer to make a file named after the object
                out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        files.writeFile(objectSomething)));
                //the first line would be ID
                out.write(Integer.toString(objectID));
                //second line would be the name
                out.write(objectName)
                //Theres two possible IOexceptions, 
                //one for using the writer
                //and one for closing the writer
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

In this example, I have used "objectSomething" as the **string** name of the file, objectID and objectName are the int and string respectively that your file contains.

to read this data, pretty straightforward:

```
public static void load(FileIO files) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            // Reads file called ObjectSomething
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    files.readFile(ObjectSomething)));

            // Loads values from the file one line at a time
            varID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            varName = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

here, I've used varID and varName as local variables in this class that you would use if you needed them in your code throughout your application.